# Simple plane subdivision doesn't work as expected

Tags: interface, edit-mode

I am trying to subdivide part of the plane, which I selected using "Select" > "Select Random" option. The problem is that after selecting the planes and then right click to subdivide it also creates n-gons, and just subdivides it in a weird way which it never used to do before. Why is it doing that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This tool subdivides the selected edges, then connect the new verts with eachother.

Comment: So what tool would just subdivide it without connecting anything?

Comment: What result wrt. topology are you expecting, perhaps you can add a sketch? If the unselected parts are not supposed to be subdivided, then this naturally results in triangles or n-gons.

Comment: Have you read documentation about this functionality?  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/subdivide.html It works as described in the article

Comment: I think that tool not exist. I'm not sure what you want to do, but you can use poke faces (it's diagonal) or may be you can try the discombobulator add-on. It's built in, just enable in the preferences. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_mesh/discombobulator.html